# How to use stream on method that return boolean value with multiple condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using this method:

```
private boolean getUsageDisabled(controlUnitVersion cUv) {
  Partnumber partn=cUv.getcontrolUnit().getpartnumber();

  for (controlUnit cu: partn.getcontrolUnit()) {
    for (ControlUnitVersion cUv2: cu.getcontrolUnitVersion()) {
      for (release r: cUv2.getRelease()) {
        if (r.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("locked") || 
          r.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("released")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and I want to be able to change it using Stream , I've tried the following, but I am missing something:

```
partn.getcontrolUnit()
  .stream()
  .forEach(cu -> cu.getControlUnitVersion()
    .stream()
    .filter(cUv2 -> cUv2.getrelease()
      .stream()
      .forEach(release -> {
        if (release.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("locked") ||
          release.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("released")) {
          return true; 
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

but I am getting an error.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of a list, and you want to perform some computation in the nested list with the stream. The flatMap() method could resolve your problem.

And you want to return a boolean, if there are any elements in stream that match a given condition, anyMatch() might be a good choice.

```
partn.getcontrolUnit().stream()
.flatMap(cu -> cu.getcontrolUnitVersion().stream())
.anyMatch(r -> r.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("locked") || r.getWorkflowState().getKey().equals("released"));
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for the suggestion. By the way, SO has suggested changes feature, feel free to correct my answer :)

Comment: well, using a map for each condition is nice. But in that case, i am not sure in the stream pipeline implementation, is it would transform the whole stream, and then apply you terminal operation (say findFirst()). With anyMatch(), i assume it would immediately return the value when an element is satisfied condition

Comment: yes after re-read the above comments, i think it should be done that way for cleaner code

Comment: furthermore, using `.map(r -> r.getWorkflowState().getKey()).anyMatch(k -> k.equals("locked") || k.equals("released"))` would be good for readability.

Comment: @user16320675 yeah, i saw your answer after i added my comment. but i disagree you got some step further, it's not different at all.